# Class Not found for ContextLoaderListener in a GWT, GAE, Maven and Spring application

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, maven-gae-plugin

I am very new to the GWT(Google Web ToolKit), GAE(Google App Engine) stack. I am in need of writing this application and uploading it to GAE.

The project uses maven as a build and deploy management tool.

Here is the issue:

1) I import the project as a Maven project inn my eclipse( Eclipse is equipped with the m2e eclipse plugin, gwt and gae plugin)

2) By default the GAE nature is turned off, so when I run it as a GWT Web application, it runs fine.

3) When I turn on the GAE feature to deploy it to the GAE using eclipse, it throws an error that the **App Engine SDK is not a valid directory**, because maven considers the jar to be the SDK home (I know this is stupid) and this is addressed in this [StackOverFlow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992693/why-does-eclipse-consider-that-the-app-engine-sdk-jar-is-the-directory-where-the).

4) The solution worked and I was able to get rid of this error when I moved the Maven 
Dependencies at the bottom in the `Java Build Path` of the library tab.

5) **Problem is** : This screws up the other dependencies which were to be loaded by Maven in the beginning (like Spring's `ContextLoaderListener`) and throws a `ClassNotFound` for this class. MOreover, I feel it will give me other exceptions as well because I moved Maven Dependencies at the bottom.

Here is the relevant part of my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<properties>
<!-- client -->
<!-- Get the latest GXT release through support 3.0.6... -->
<gxt.version>3.0.1</gxt.version>
<gwt.version>2.5.1</gwt.version>
<gwtp.version>1.0</gwtp.version>
<gin.version>2.0.0</gin.version>
<gwtquery.version>1.3.2</gwtquery.version>


<!-- server -->
<guice.version>3.0</guice.version>
<mysql.version>5.1.26</mysql.version>

<spring.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>


<!-- testing -->
<junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
<jukito.version>1.1</jukito.version>

<!-- maven -->
<gwt-maven-plugin.version>2.5.1</gwt-maven-plugin.version>
<maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.6</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
<maven-compiler-plugin.version>2.3.2</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
<maven-resources-plugin.version>2.5</maven-resources-plugin.version>
<maven-processor-plugin.version>2.0.5</maven-processor-plugin.version>
<maven-build-helper-plugin.version>1.7</maven-build-helper-plugin.version>

<target.jdk>1.6</target.jdk>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

<!-- REST -->
<resteasy.version>3.0.2.Final</resteasy.version>
<arcbees.version>1.1.1</arcbees.version>

<!-- GAE -->
<gae.version>1.8.4</gae.version>
<gae.home>${settings.localRepository}/com/google/appengine/appengine-java- 
sdk/${gae.version}/appengine-java-sdk-${gae.version}</gae.home>

<webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}   
</webappDirectory>
</properties>

<build>
    <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <plugins>



    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gae.version}</version>
    </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>${target.jdk}</source>
      <target>${target.jdk}</target>
      <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${gwt.version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <gwtSdkFirstInClasspath>true</gwtSdkFirstInClasspath>
      <strict>true</strict>

      <testTimeOut>180</testTimeOut>
      <includes>**/*GwtTestSuite.java</includes>
      <excludes>**/*GwtTest.java</excludes>
      <mode>htmlunit</mode>

      <extraJvmArgs>-Xss1024K -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M</extraJvmArgs>
      <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>
      <style>${gwt.style}</style>

      <copyWebapp>true</copyWebapp>
      <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>

      <runTarget>Sample.html</runTarget>
      <modules>
        <module>com.sample.Sample</module>
      </modules>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>test</goal>
          <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

 </plugins>


  </build>

  <dependencies>

      <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>${gae.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- GXT -->
<!-- http://docs.sencha.com/gxt-guides/3/ -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sencha.gxt</groupId>
  <artifactId>gxt</artifactId>
  <version>${gxt.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sencha.gxt</groupId>
  <artifactId>gxt-chart</artifactId>
  <version>${gxt.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Google Web Toolkit -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
  <version>${gwt.version}</version>
</dependency>

    <!-- GWT-Platform -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwtp-mvp-client</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwtp-dispatch-client</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwtp-dispatch-server-guice</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwtp-dispatch-rest</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtp.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwtp-dispatch-shared</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtp.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- DI -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
      <version>${guice.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
      <artifactId>guice-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${guice.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
      <artifactId>guice-assistedinject</artifactId>
      <version>${guice.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>gin</artifactId>
      <version>${gin.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.gwtquery</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwtquery</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtquery.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.arcbees</groupId>
            <artifactId>guicy-resteasy</artifactId>
            <version>${arcbees.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
       <version>${mysql.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>    
</project>
```

Could anyone please suggest a way to fix this issue?

Thanks for reading it till the end.

Comment: Did you `mvn package` your app to copy the dependencies to your `target/<finalName>/WEB-INF/lib`, and use the correct _WAR directory?_ See https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq#gwt_with_maven

Comment: I used the war directory correctly. But I am not sure if I `mvn package` it . Thanks for the hint. Will check this and update

Comment: You'll generally not have a `target/<finalName>` if you haven't run `mvn package` (or similar, such as `mvn war:exploded`). So if you used _the war directory correctly_, it'd mean you did `mvn package` at some point.