# The selected App Engine SDK is not valid

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am trying to create an Google Web application project in Eclipse and in the initial step of the wizard I get the following error.

> The selected App Engine SDK is not valid: SDK directory '/path_to_directory/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.3.0_1473617060_linux_gtk_x86_64/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.6/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.6' does not exist

I  tried updating the AppEngine and now have App Engine 1.8.8 and then tried to manually configure the SDK. However, it said that it failed to initialize the SDK. I am using java-oracle-7 and have set the JDK compiler compliance level at 1.7.

How do I get it to recognize the SDK?

Comment: have you updated your sdk recently?

Comment: The below solution is not working for me.  Have you resolved this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5561779/399805

That reply, in similar question, resolves this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like same with my problem, you can follow my steps:

1. Download SDK v1.8.6 (https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/downloads/detail?name=appengine-java-sdk-1.8.6.zip&can=1&q=)
2. Create folder "com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.6" in '/path_to_directory/eclipse/plugins/'
3. Unzip SDK v1.8.6 in '/path_to_directory/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.6/'
4. Create file "SdkBundleRegistrant.properties" under '/path_to_directory/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.6/' folder and type the following code:

   ```
   sdkType=GAE
   sdkBundlePath=appengine-java-sdk-1.8.6
   ```
5. Create file 'MANIFEST.MF' under '/path_to_directory/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.6/META-INF/' and type following code:

   ```
   Manifest-Version: 1.0
   Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
   Bundle-Name: Google App Engine Java SDK
   Bundle-SymbolicName: com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle
   Bundle-Version: 1.8.6
   Bundle-Vendor: Google Inc.
   Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime
   Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5
   Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
   ```
6. Restart eclipse

Comment: I have this problem with 1.8.8 impossible to install, but with these instructions I managed to get it going!

Answer (score 1):

What worked for my was updating to java 1.7.  Appengine 1.8.2 and forward no longer work on java 1.6.x

Answer (score 1):

AppEngine SDK doesn't comes under eclipse plugin. so that, we have to download manually from the below URL and configure it under project -> properties -> App engine SDK.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/download